# Jump links going to the correct page but wrong section

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress.com

I have multiple jump links destinations on 1 page but it all goes to the bottom of the correct page.

My target code looks like this:

```
<h3 style="text-align:justify;"><a name="grt"></a>Guarantor</h3>
<h3 style="text-align:justify;"><a name="sg"></a>Social Guarantor</h3>
<h3><a name="pwd"></a>Persons with disabilities</h3>
```

My link there looks like this:

`<a href="http://melissalsh.com/#grt" target="_blank" rel="noopener">`

`<a href="http://melissalsh.com/#pwd" target="_blank" rel="noopener">`

`<a href="http://melissalsh.com/#sg" target="_blank" rel="noopener">`

It all goes to the correct page but at the very bottom of the page. help please?

Comment: To link to a specific location on a web page, use an anchor tag and the id attribute instead of name
<a href="#destination"></a>
<h1 id="destination">Heading Text</h1>

Comment: Check your console for any javascript errors that might be causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To link to a specific location on a web page, use an anchor tag and the id attribute instead of name 
Like : `<a href="#destination"></a> <h1 id="destination">Heading Text</h1>`

```
<h3 style="text-align:justify;"><a id="grt"></a>Guarantor</h3>
<h3 style="text-align:justify;"><a id="pwd"></a>Guarantor</h3>
<h3 style="text-align:justify;"><a id="sg"></a>Guarantor</h3>


<a href="http://melissalsh.com/#grt" target="_blank" rel="noopener">

<a href="http://melissalsh.com/#pwd" target="_blank" rel="noopener">

<a href="http://melissalsh.com/#sg" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
```

Comment: I've tried that but it is worst as it just opens back to the same post as where the link is

Comment: sure. this is the page I have the text:

https://melissalsh.com/2017/10/14/the-all-new-insolvency-act/

The word "Guarantors" should link to:

https://melissalsh.com/glossary/#grt

But as you can see, it goes to the bottom of the page.

To clarify, I've anchored each word with different id name. so the "guarantor" SHOULD have went to grt.

Comment: @Melissa the links I tried are working for me. When exactly do you get this problem? i.e. What browser & OS, is it just with particular links etc

Comment: Hi Fluffy Kitten, I am using Google Chrome. I have problems with all the links I have. It all goes to the same page, but to the bottom of the page instead of its individual destination.